# Cast struct c/c++

Tags: c

Galera estou vendo um codigo de um network sniffer e nao estou entendendo as seguintes linhas :

```
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
```

como funcionam esses cast com struct?

```
//////////////////////////função
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

 static int count = 1;                   

 /* declare pointers to packet headers */
 const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  
 const struct sniff_ip *ip;              
 const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            
 const char *payload;                  

 int size_ip;
 int size_tcp;
 int size_payload;

 printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
 count++;


 ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet); ////////

 ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);//////////
 size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
 if (size_ip < 20) {
  printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
  return;
 }


 printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
 printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));


 switch(ip->ip_p) {
  case IPPROTO_TCP:
   printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
   break;
  case IPPROTO_UDP:
   printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
   return;
  case IPPROTO_ICMP:
   printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
   return;
  case IPPROTO_IP:
   printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
   return;
  default:
   printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
   return;
 }
```

Comment: Os *casts* nao tem razao de ser no codigo apresentado. Ao fazer uma atribuicao a uma variavel de um valor de tipo diferente mas compativel o compilador faz uma conversao automatica. A presenca do cast nem ajuda nem desajuda antes pelo contrario.

Answer (score 1):

A função `got_packet` recebe o argumento `cont u_char* packet`, que é um `array` de caracteres que contêm os bytes do pacote recebido.

A `struct sniff_ethernet` representa o cabeçalho Ethernet que possui 6 bytes para o endereço de destino, 6 bytes para o endereço origem e 2 bytes para [EtherType](http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~andre/documentos/ethernet.html). Então os primeiros 16 bytes do `array` de caracteres `packet` são destinados a essa `struct`.

A `struct sniff_ip` representa o cabeçalho `IP` por sua vez, está pegando as informações que estão no `array packet` e inserindo na `struct` para melhor manipulação.

```
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
```

`packet + SIZE_ETHERNET`, significa que tu estás a pegar o endereço de `packet`, e somando com o tamanho do cabeçalho Ethernet, ou seja vai estar atribuindo a essa `struct` somente as informações do cabeçalho `IP`.

Dessa forma, os primeiros bytes do `array packet` estão na `struct sniff_ethernet` e os próximos na `struct sniff_ip`, e assim por diante.